# Does this Public Method Which Calls a Private Method Contain Unnecessary Redundancy?

Tags: oop

Let's say I have a public method as shown below:

```
    public void startService(int intParam1, int intParam2, boolean booleanParam) {
        setupService(intParam1, intParam2, booleanParam); // call private method to perform prerequisites

        // perform remaining logic to start service here
    }
```

This method has a call to a private method inside the same class which has the same interface as the public method which calls it. The public **startService()** method is the only consumer of the private **setupService()** method.

Would it have been a better idea to just get rid of the private **setupService()** method call and just replace it with **setupService()**'s implementation? In this case it appears there is some redundancy that may be unnecessary but I'd like to get some professional opinions. I've run into this several times in my career but usually looked the other way in fear of breaking something.

Comment: How big are the two functions? Often it can be better to refactor a long, complicated, and self-contained chunk of code into a separate function for no other reason than that it's long and complicated.

Comment: That's a great question - setupService() is 50 lines of code and startService() is 25 lines of code.

Comment: In that case, I probably would have split off at least two private methods. As a rule of thumb, I don't like methods getting more than 20-25 lines long (although that's just a rule of thumb; there can be exceptions), and especially if that's actually 25 lines of dense complexity instead of, say, adding 25 widgets to a flat view.

Comment: FYI, when someone asks how big a method is, lines of code is a rather poor metric to use. Better would be to reference cyclomatic complexity (i.e., the number of decision points in the code.)

Comment: Thanks for the information as I never thought of it that way before. Excellent tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this often too.

I ask myself:

- Is the private function doing too many things that could be further broken up into functions? If so, then I would much rather get rid of the single private function and call the smaller functions from within the public function. This makes the code more readable because you can at once glance see what the public method is doing. This goes well towards making code self-documenting too.
- Is there a possiblity of a future use-case where that single private function might be used again? If not, then it is not needed to be made private at the moment. However, it can get difficult in the future if a part of the code in your public function has to be used by other functions (more testing during the transition).

All in all, it comes down to having optimal modularity in your functions. If the private function cannot be further broken down into independent functions, then I would just get rid of it and put its code as is in the public method.